# Using pre-existing character vectors in quasiquotation of an expression with rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

Sometimes when working with `dplyr` one has a character vector of column names that's to be used to operate on data, for instance:

```
 cols_of_interest <- c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")
```

In `dplyr` 0.5.0 and earlier, the recommended approach to this problem was to use the `verb_` underscore construct as follows:

```
library("tidyverse")
my_cols <- c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")
iris %>%
  select_(.dots = my_cols)
```

The `verb_` functions are now deprecated in favour of the new tidy evaluation framework (dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) introduced by the `rlang` library.

As of `dplyr` 0.7.0 the following works without any special accommodations:

```
library("tidyverse")
# library("rlang")
my_cols <- c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")
iris %>%
  select(my_cols)
```

Note that in development builds of `dplyr`, this was not the case

### Motivation

Selecting columns in Shiny apps is a good example use case, this is how one could do it using `verb_` notation

```
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")
library("DT")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("cols_to_show",
                "Columns to show",
                choices = colnames(iris),
                multiple = TRUE),
    dataTableOutput("verb_table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$verb_table <- renderDataTable({
      iris %>%
        select_(.dots = input$cols_to_show)

    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pre 0.5.0 `dplyr` the underlying framework for non-standard evaluation was `lazyeval` and required special consideration for strings. Hadley Wickham released a fundamentally new version of `dplyr` with a new underbelly called `rlang` which provides a more consistent framework for non-standard evaluation. This was version 0.70 - here's an explanation of why 0.6.0 was skipped - https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/

The following now works without any special considerations:

```
library("tidyverse")
my_cols <- c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")
iris %>%
  select(my_cols)
```

Note that the new `rlang` framework adds the ability to have a vector of naked symbols using quosures

```
my_quos <- quos(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
iris %>%
  select(!!!my_quos)
```

You can read more about programming with `dplyr` here - http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

### Comparison in Shiny

```
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")
library("DT")
library("rlang")
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "cols_to_show",
      "Columns to show",
      choices = colnames(iris),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    dataTableOutput("verb_table"),
    dataTableOutput("tidyeval_table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$verb_table <- renderDataTable({
      iris %>%
        select_(.dots = input$cols_to_show)

    })

    output$tidyeval_table <- renderDataTable({
      iris %>%
        select(!!!syms(input$cols_to_show))

    })
  }
)
```

Comment: It only became clear that this was about a particular package named `rlang` after you posted an answer to your question. Hence my downvote for the question.

Comment: @42- it's not about rlang, it's about dplyr and the tidyeval framework. I don't see anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr 0.6, `select()` now understands both column names and column positions. Previously it would only understand the latter. So you don't need `syms()` anymore because this now works: `select(mtcars, c("cyl", "disp"), "am")`.

Comment: I didn't make my question explicit enough that I was asking about the problem of programming with dplyr, where column names can't be given interactively as string but instead a pre-existing character vector exists.

Comment: Your answer above is the most general one. In general, programming in dplyr amounts to building quoted expressions. So character vectors of column names should indeed be transformed to symbols with `rlang::syms()` (or any other suitable way, e.g. `lapply(x, as.name))`. `select()` is an exception because it now accepts strings.

Comment: so I wrote this answer/question against 0.6.0 and there are some (AWESOME) changes in the actually released 0.70 version